# Java fraction counter with classes

Tags: java, arrays, counter

I am very stuck on an assignment for some reason. I have a program that reads fractions from an input file, assigns each line to a string, and then saves the contents to the class Fraction (numerator and denominator). The fraction object is then saved into an array called `fractionList`.

I have another class `FractionCounter` that counts the occurrences of fractions in their reduced form, and if there are any repeats then the program will simply add to the integer "counter" of that object. The `FractionCounter` objects are stored in an object list called `fracCount`.

My problem is when I am adding an object to the `fracCount` list of `FractionCounter` objects. I am using a branching statement to determine whether I should add a new fraction element (one that doesn't match any of the reduced form of the other fractions in the array `fracCount`) to `fracCount`, or if I should add a value to the `counter` variable in an element that shares the same reduced fraction value.

Everything works except when I am trying to determine whether the faction object is a copy or not. With the code I have, my `fracCount` array is empty.

Here is my code

```
public class Fraction {
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    Fraction(){ // default, no arg constructor
    }
    // constructor that initializes data
    Fraction(int numerator, int denominator){
        this.numerator = numerator;
        if(denominator > 1000){
            this.denominator = 1;
        }else if(numerator == denominator){
            this.numerator = 1;
            this.denominator = 1;
        }else if(denominator == 0){
            System.out.println("Zero is not a valid denominator");
        }else{
            this.denominator = denominator;
        }
    }
    // compares this fraction object to 'other' fraction object
    boolean equals(Fraction other){
        if(this.numerator == other.numerator && 
                this.denominator == other.denominator){
            return true;
        }else if((this.numerator / this.denominator) ==
                (other.numerator / other.denominator)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    // gives user access to the numerator and denominator
    public int getNumerator(){
        return this.numerator;
    }
    public int getDenominator(){
        return this.denominator;
    }   
}

public class FractionCounter extends Fraction{
    private Fraction theFraction;
    private int counter = 1;

    FractionCounter(Fraction theFraction){
        this.theFraction = theFraction;
    }
    public boolean compareAndIncrement(Fraction newFraction){
        if((theFraction.getNumerator() / theFraction.getDenominator() == 
                newFraction.getNumerator() / newFraction.getDenominator())){
            this.counter++;
            return true;
        }else if(theFraction.getDenominator() == 0 || 
                newFraction.getDenominator() == 0){
            return false;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public class ObjectList {
    private int N;
    private Fraction[] fractionList;
    private int numElements = 0;

    public ObjectList(int n){
        this.N = n;
        this.fractionList = new Fraction[N];
    }
    public void add(Fraction next){
        fractionList[numElements] = next;
        numElements++;
    }
    public int size(){
        return this.numElements;
    }
    public Fraction getFraction(int i){
        return fractionList[i];
    }
}

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.awt.List;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class FractionDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        // creates scanner object
        Scanner fractions = null;

        // uses scanner to import fractions file and read how many lines 
        try{
            fractions = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("fractions.txt"));
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Cannot find fractions.txt");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // creates a large array that stores the text file
        String[] input = new String[100];

        int numLines = 0; // counts the number of fractions
        int numElement = 0; // counts the current index element
        while(fractions.hasNextLine()){
            input[numElement] = fractions.next();
            numElement++;
            numLines++;
        }
        fractions.close(); // closes the input stream

        // create object list of fractions
        ObjectList fractionList = new ObjectList(numLines);
        ObjectList fractCount = new ObjectList(numLines);

        int totalFractions = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < numLines; i++){

            totalFractions++; // adds one on every new line

            // creates an array for each fraction where frac[0] is the 
            // numerator and frac[1] is the denominator
            String[] fract = input[i].split("/"); 

            // converts the string values to integers
            int numerator = Integer.parseInt(fract[0]);
            int denom = Integer.parseInt(fract[1]);

            // creates a fraction object and assigns instance variables
            Fraction f = new Fraction(numerator, denom);
            FractionCounter count = new FractionCounter(f);

            // adds the fraction to the array if the denominator
            // is not zero
            if(f.getDenominator() != 0){
                fractionList.add(f);
                for(int j = 0; j < totalFractions; j++){
                    if(fractCount.getFraction(j) != null){
                        if(!f.equals(fractCount.getFraction(j))){
                            fractCount.add(count);
                        }else{
                            count.compareAndIncrement(f);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very natural way to check if two simple fractions are equal by value without converting them to floating-point numbers.

If `a/b = c/d`, then `ad = bc` (except for `b` or `d` = 0), so:

```
boolean equals(Fraction other) {
    if (this.denominator == 0 || other.denominator == 0)
         return false; // undefined
    return this.numerator * other.denominator == other.numerator * this.denominator;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem that you are dividing ints?

```
  numerator/denominator
```

What happens when you divide say, *4/6* and *1/7* ? With ints they will both yield 0 so you get an unexpected equality.

You can convert to double

```
  (double)numerator/(double)demoninator
```

but remember that floating point comparison for equality is not obvious, usually we test

```
 if ( ( oneDouble - anotherDouble ) < someTinyValue )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the line that is giving you problems (in the `.equals` method of `Fraction`:

```
 (this.numerator / this.denominator) == (other.numerator / other.denominator)
```

It is currently performing integer division, so 1/2 == 0 and 1/3 == 0, so your code considers EVERY fraction to already be in the list of fractions.

You'll want to perform floating point arithmetic with some sort of epsilon.

[Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate/21895757#21895757)